# Как проверить нет ли пустых значений в массиве char[]?

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Условно имеем массив чаров `char[] grid`. Нужно выполнить условие, скажем `game.setGameStatus(DRAW)` только в том случае, если в целом массиве не осталось пустых мест (все игроки завершили ход и все клетки заняты). Если использовать цикл `for` с аргументом `char с != 0`, то `game.setGameStatus(DRAW)` исполняется сразу после заполнения элемента с индексом 0.

`Arrays.asList(grid).contains(null)` тоже не дает правильного результата. Вот как выглядит сам цикл:

```
for (char c : grid) {
    if (c != 0
        && game.getGameStatus() != GameStatus.X_WON
        && game.getGameStatus() != GameStatus.Y_WON) {
       game.setGameStatus(GameStatus.DRAW);
    }
}
```

Как проверить массив чтобы в нем не было `null` ? Проверка производится в методе `makeMove`, то есть после каждого хода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо пройти весь цикл и если там не обнаружилось нулей, то продолжать

```
boolean f = false;
for (char c : grid) {
    if (c == 0) { f = true; break; }
}
if (!f && game.getGameStatus() != GameStatus.X_WON
       && game.getGameStatus() != GameStatus.Y_WON) {
        game.setGameStatus(GameStatus.DRAW);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут несколько моментов.

Первое, это то как у вас представлены пустые поля.

`char` - примитивный тип, т.е. переменная такого не может иметь значение `null`.
А значит и пустые места не могут обозначаться с помощью `null`. Нужно либо использовать какой-то символ из допустимых значений `char` - т.е. любой unicode символ, например пробел и тогда проверка `является ли поле пустым` будет выражаться так: `c == ' '`.

Либо нужно менять тип массива на `Character[]`. `Character` в отличии от `char` - ссылочный тип, т.е. может быть `null`. Тогда `null` может обозначать пустую клетку и проверка будет `c != null`.

Теперь используя один из подходов описанных выше для обозначения пустых полей, собственно проверка, что все поля непустые:

```
Character[] grid = ...;
boolean existsEmptyField = false;
for (Character c : grid) {
   if (c == null) {
      existsEmptyField = true;
      break;
   }
}
if (!existsEmptyField) {
   // тут мы точно знаем, что все заполнено
}
```